# LEFT JOIN but with WHERE criteria, rows getting lost

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

I have a simple database with three tables.  In the database I have a table for users of my system, a table for applications to a competition, and an intermediary table that allows me to track which users have selected which applications to view.

Table 1 = users (user_id, username, first, last, etc...)
Table 2 = applications (application_id, company_name, url, etc...)
Table 3 = picks (pick_id, user_id, application_id, picked)

I am trying to write an SQL query that will show all the applications that have been submitted and if any individual application has been selected by a user will show that it has been "picked" (1=picked, 0=not picked).

So for user_id = 1 I'd like to see:

Column Names (application_id, company_name, picked)

1, Foo, 1
2, Bar, 1
3, Alpha, Null
4, Beta, Null

I tried it with the following query:

```
SELECT applications.application_id, applications.company_name, picks.picked
  FROM applications
  LEFT JOIN picks ON applications.application_id = picks.application_id
 ORDER BY applications.application_id ASC
```

Which is returning this:

1, Foo, 1
1, Foo, 1
2, Bar, null
3, Alpha, null
4, Beta, null

I have a second user (user_id = 2) that also picked application 1 ("Foo") which I know is returning the second row.

Then I tried to limit the scope by specifying user_id = 1 here:

`SELECT applications.application_id, applications.company_name, picks.picked 
  FROM applications 
  LEFT JOIN picks ON applications.application_id = picks.application_id
  WHERE user_id = 1 
  ORDER BY applications.application_id ASC`

Now I'm only getting:

1, Foo, 1

Any suggestions on how I can get what I'm looking for?  Again, ideally for a single user I'd like to see:

Column Names (application_id, company_name, picked)

1, Foo, 1
2, Bar, 1
3, Alpha, Null
4, Beta, Null

Comment: Is this mysql or SQL-server? Name the appropriate only, please

Comment: Sorry - just mysql.  I chose sql-server by accident.

Comment: You should  join the users table in order to specify the user

Comment: Thanks, John.  That's what I was thinking.  Any suggestions on how to write the query?

Comment: After your left join just add `join users u on u.user_id = picks.user_id ` that way its an inner join so it will filter appropriately.. You could also add an and clause on the join for the user id to be equal to one or just keep it in the WHERE.. but remember to reference the users user_id in the where clause

Comment: Thanks for the help, John.  I updated the sql query as follows: <br /><br />

SELECT applications.application_id, applications.company_name, picks.picked FROM applications LEFT JOIN picks ON applications.application_id = picks.application_id JOIN users u on u.user_id = picks.user_id WHERE u.user_id = 1 ORDER BY applications.application_id ASC <br /> <br />

But now I'm only getting one row of data:<br /><br />

1, Foo, 1 <br /><br />

How can I get it to give me:

1, Foo, 1 <br />
2, Bar, null <br />
3, Alpha, null <br /><br />

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data? What's the user_id for the rows returned without the where clause?

Comment: John - I have to run (my Dad died on Tuesday) but I'll be back online later on tonight.

Comment: Condolences! take care of yourself and your family!

Comment: I'm sorry for your loss! You should take some time off!

Comment: And thanks to the rest of y'all for the kind words and the assistance on solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a so-called join table in your database schema. In your case it's called `picks`. This allows you to create a many-to-many relationship between your `users` and `applications`.

To use that join table correctly you need to join all three tables. These queries are easier to write if you use table aliases (`applications AS a`, etc.)

```
SELECT a.application_id, a.company_name, p.picked, u.user_id, u.username
  FROM applications AS a
  LEFT JOIN picks AS p ON a.application_id = p.application_id
  LEFT JOIN users AS u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
 ORDER BY a.application_id, u.user_id
```

This will give you a list of all applications with the users who have made them. If no users are related to an application, the `LEFT JOIN` operations will retain the application row and you'll see NULL values for columns from the `picks` and `users` table.

Now, if you add a `WHERE p.something = something` or `u.something = something` clause to this query in an attempt to narrow down the presentation, it has the effect of converting the `LEFT JOIN` clauses into `INNER JOIN` clauses. That is, you won't retain the `applications` rows that don't have matching rows in the other tables.

If you want to retain those unmatched rows in your result set, put the condition in the first `ON` clause instead of the `WHERE` clause, like so.

```
SELECT a.application_id, a.company_name, p.picked, u.user_id, u.username
  FROM applications AS a
  LEFT JOIN picks AS p ON a.application_id = p.application_id AND p.user_id = 1
  LEFT JOIN users AS u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
 ORDER BY a.application_id, u.user_id
```

**Edit** Many join tables like your `picks` table are set up with a composite primary key, in your example `(application_id, user_id)`. That ensures just one row per possible relationship between the tables being joined.  In your case you have the potential for multiple such rows.

To use only the most recent of those rows (the one with the highest `pick_id`) takes a little more work. You need a subquery (virtual table) to extract it, and to retrieve the appropriate value of `picked` so your query works.  So now things get interesting.

```
SELECT MAX(pick_id) AS pick_id, 
       application_id, user_id
  FROM picks
 GROUP BY application_id, user_id
```

retrieves the unique relationship pair. That is good. But next we have to fetch the `picked` column detail value from those rows. That takes another join, using the MAX value of `pick_id`, like so

```
SELECT q.application_id, q.user_id, r.picked
  FROM (
        SELECT MAX(pick_id) AS pick_id,
               application_id, user_id
          FROM picks
         GROUP BY application_id, user_id
       ) AS q
  JOIN picks AS r ON q.pick_id = r.pick_id
```

So, we need to substitute this little virtual table (subquery) in place of the `pick AS p` table in the original query.  That looks like this.

```
SELECT a.application_id, a.company_name, p.picked, u.user_id, u.username
  FROM applications AS a
  LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT q.application_id, q.user_id, r.picked
          FROM (
                SELECT MAX(pick_id) AS pick_id,
                       application_id, user_id
                  FROM picks
                 GROUP BY application_id, user_id
               ) AS q
          JOIN picks AS r ON q.pick_id = r.pick_id
            ) AS p ON a.application_id = p.application_id AND p.user_id = 1
  LEFT JOIN users AS u ON p.user_id = u.user_id
 ORDER BY a.application_id, u.user_id
```

Some developers prefer to create `VIEW` objects for subqueries like the one here, rather than creating a club sandwich of a query like this one. It's not called *Structured* Query Language on a foolish whim, eh? These subqueries sometimes can be elements of a structure.

Comment: StackOverflowians to the rescue again!  Thanks for the great answer, Ollie.  This works like a charm.  I appreciate your help.  JL

Comment: Ollie - quick follow-up on this...In the picks table a user can select or unselect an entry (it's very helpful to watch this activity as it happens).  What that means, though, is that for one particular application (say application_id = 1) you might have 3 votes: select-unselect-select.  With the latter query you proposed (which worked great) I now get three rows for application_id = 1.  What do you think is the easiest way to display only the most recent pick?  I tried using LIMIT but couldn't figure it out.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: Jean-Luc, do you mean you get three new rows inserted into `picks` for the select-unselect-select operations? If so, you will need the one with the largest `id value.

Comment: Ollie - You are the man.  Seriously.  I was trying to figure this out on my own (combing through countless stackoverflow threads) and would have never been able to make sense of how to use MAX and GROUP BY in a subquery.  I really appreciate your help!